# Angular service worker debugging information under ngsw/state virtual directory?

Tags: angular-service-worker

I am in reference to angular service workers and debugging (see following link: https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#locating-and-analyzing-debugging-information).

To quote the documentation:

> The Angular service worker exposes debugging information under the
>   `ngsw/` virtual directory. Currently, the single exposed URL is
>   `ngsw/state`.

I haven't been able to find the `ngsw/state` debugging information on the https://angular.io/ progressive web app: I tried appending `ngsw/state` as follows: https://angular.io/ngsw/state to no avail. I could neither find the `ngsw/state` reference within the source devtools tab. What's more: what is a ***virtual directory*** and where is it to be found?

Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some reason the service workers seem not to be activated on the https://angular.io progressive web app although I might be wrong (see: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/.angular-cli.json#L25).

However by using the angular CLI to generate a service worker app:

```
ng new mySwProject --service-worker
```

then building it in **prod** mode:

```
cd mySwProject
ng build --prod
```

and serving it with **http-server**:

```
cd dist
http-server -p 8080
```

one can view service worker information by using the following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/ngsw/state
```

Output:

```
NGSW Debug Info:

Driver state: NORMAL ((nominal))
Latest manifest hash: e60b43d83d323671c26f71fba9da395abdb4c01b
Last update check: 14s821u

=== Version e60b43d83d323671c26f71fba9da395abdb4c01b ===

Clients: 

=== Idle Task Queue ===
Last update tick: 14s616u
Last update run: never
Task queue:



Debug log:
```

FYI: `ng serve` does not work with service worker as stated in the documentation:

> As ng serve does not work with service workers, you must use a real
>   HTTP server to test your project locally. It's a good idea to test on
>   a dedicated port.

Comment: As I tested, the problem is exactly the opposite. https://angular.io/ngsw/state works and shows debug information. But the way you said in this answer doesn't work. The first difference is that `build --prod` would build in `dist/mySwProject`, not in `dist`. It is expected due to `"outputPath": "dist/mySwProject"` build option in `angular.json` file. The second is after `cd dist/mySwProject` and running `http-server -p 8080` you will get `"GET /ngsw/state" Error (404): "Not found"` on `http://localhost:8080/ngsw/state`. This is also expected. [See next comment]

Comment: Because the path/file doesn't exist actually and you don't configure any fallback (like [fallback to `index.html`](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml)) for this `http-server`. As an immediate solution, I used `angular-http-server` instead. It fallbacks to `index.html` and you can see in its logs: `Route ...\mySwProject\dist\mySwProject\ngsw\state, replacing with index.html`. But this simply shows the app home page!

Comment: I don't know what happens! But now (after some regular events like refreshes, openning and closing Chrome DevTools, ...) both (`http-server` and `angular-http-server`) work. But in my production web-server (Nginx) Service-Worker still shows the app's home page!